# How do I get outlook to show me emails I have flagged from my personal inbox as well as the shared inbox?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, taskbar, microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-outlook-2016, to-do

Could someone please advise on how I can get my to do bar on outlook to show all emails I have flagged within my own inbox as well as only the emails I have flagged in the shared inbox in the taskbar pane?

Comment: Have you had a chance to see the suggestions provided? You can post back if you have further questions about this.

Answer (score 0):

In the post
[Flagging email in a shared mailbox doesn't show the email in To-Do List on the Tasks tab](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/flagging-email-in-a-shared-mailbox-doesnt-show-the/c5fb936b-add8-42a1-aadf-3ba847f4d0cf),
a Microsoft Moderator made this answer in January 2022:

> Based on your requirement, we have checked at our end with all possible settings and seems it’s isn’t feasible to show other shared mailbox flagging emails in To-do list. At this moment, To-do list only shows own mailbox flagging email. As this feature is related with product, so if needed you can submit your feedback to Outlook product development team via go to **Help > Feedback**.

So it seems that Outlook isn't designed to have this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Add the shared mailbox as an additional account via File > Add account, enter the email address of the shared mailbox, leave the password box blank and then restart Outlook, when prompted to enter credentials, input your own user account and password to pass the authentication.
More detailed instructions, you can refer to: [How to add a shared mailbox as additional account in Outlook (2022 version)](https://www.michev.info/blog/post/3567/how-to-add-a-shared-mailbox-as-additional-account-in-outlook-2022-version).
[image]

Based on my test in Outlook 2016, this can make flagged emails in both primary mailbox and the shared mailbox show in the to do task bar:
[image]
[image]